# Adding an interpolated function to neural networks through ElementwiseLayer

Tags: interpolation, neural-networks

1.Trying to add an interpolated function to neural networks.

```
ifun = Interpolation[Table[{x, Tanh[x]}, {x, -100, 100, 0.2}], 
  InterpolationOrder -> 1]
Plot[{ifun[x], Tanh[x]}, {x, -4, 4}]
```

2.We implement the function.

```
net = NetChain[{30, ElementwiseLayer[ifun], 20, 
   ElementwiseLayer[ifun], 3, SoftmaxLayer[]}, "Input" -> {2}, 
  "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {Red, Green, Blue}}]]
```

3.Error

```
ElementwiseLayer::invscf: InterpolatingFunction[{{-100.,100.}},... could not be symbolically evaluated as a unary scalar function.
```

4.Please tell me how to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Using @CarlWoll's [`InterpolationToPiecewise`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/212753) will work.  `ElementWiseLayer` complains that the `InterpolatingFunction` does not "symbolically evaluate." I take that to mean that it accepts only certain expressions as symbolic expressions.

```
(* https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/212753 *)
InterpolationToPiecewise[if_, x_] := 
 Module[{main, default, grid}, grid = if["Grid"];
   Piecewise[{if@"GetPolynomial"[#, x - #], x < First@#} & /@ 
     grid[[2 ;; -2]], if@"GetPolynomial"[#, x - #] &@grid[[-1]]]] /; 
  if["InterpolationMethod"] == "Hermite";

pwfun[x_] = InterpolationToPiecewise[ifun, x];

net = NetChain[{30, ElementwiseLayer[pwfun], 20, 
   ElementwiseLayer[pwfun], 3, SoftmaxLayer[]}, "Input" -> {2}, 
  "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {Red, Green, Blue}}]]
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped.Another error occurred while training the network.
  NetTrain::interr2 : 
    An unknown internal error occurred.Consult Internal` $ \
LastInternalFailure for potential information.`` `

Consult Internal` $ LastInternalFailure

InvalidJson
Non - JSON value : {{KeyAbsent, $Failed}, {KeyAbsent, $Failed}}.

Comment: @Глеб I'm not sure what causes that.  Maybe ask another question about that issue.  Or ask Wolfram Support.  (This is somewhat similar but unanswered: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/212986/how-can-i-prevent-errors-with-replicatelayer)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, piecewise function support in `ElementwiseLayer` is somewhat limited. It doesn't allow logical disjunctions (e.g. `x<10. || x<9. ...`) which were generated when `PiecewiseFunction` automatically unified all of the -1s and 1s in the function value list. Simplifying the expression with `PiecewiseExpand` would help, but then again, this would generate unsupported conditions of the form `a < x <= b`. Seems that `ElementwiseLayer` currently only supports simple inequalities inside of `PiecewiseFunction`.

The quickest solution here (in terms of my work) is to use the `Which` construct instead of `PiecewiseFunction`:

```
InterpolationToWhich[if_, x_] := 
  Module[{grid}, grid = if["Grid"];
    Which @@ Flatten[
      {
       {x < First@#, if@"GetPolynomial"[#, x - #]} & /@ grid[[2 ;; -2]],
       True,
       if@"GetPolynomial"[#, x - #] &@grid[[-1]]
      }
    ]
  ] /; if["InterpolationMethod"] == "Hermite";

wfun[x_] = InterpolationToWhich[ifun, x];
ElementwiseLayer[wfun]
```

There's much to be optimized, though. One could use a binary tree of `If`s to reduce the layer's time complexity from linear to logarithmic.

Comment: Tank you very much.You can helped me.I am funny.